# Timezone Settings: "UTC" and "local" times are incorrect

Tags: timezones

On the "General Settings" page of my WordPress site, it's not displaying the correct UTC and local times (see screenshot below).

[image]

**The displayed UTC and local times are wrong.  It should say that local time is "15:52"**

- I'm running WordPress 4.9.6 and PHP 7.0.30.
- The default timezone in my "php.ini" file is set correctly--when I call the `date()` and `date_default_timezone_get()` functions from a standalone PHP script, they output the correct information.
- The clock on my Windows web server is correct and is set to the correct timezone.
- The time displays incorrectly when I call the following WordPress function (it is 4 hours behind what it should be): `current_time('Y-m-d H:i')`.

[This thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/utc-time-and-local-time-problems/) says the problem is caused by a bad plugin. I actually had that particular plugin installed, but deactivating (and then deleting) the plugin didn’t fix the issue for me.

[This thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/utc-time-wrong/page/2/) says it’s due to the server’s timezone definitions being corrupted. It provides instructions on how to fix this for Linux, but not Windows. However, I have other WordPress sites hosted on the same server, and they do not have this issue.

Issue has been cross-posted here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/timezone-settings-utc-and-local-times-are-incorrect/

Answer (score 0):

This is set inside your database and is also used inside PHP settings on the server.  Double check the PHP settings if you can control them. There is a timezone parameter that you can enter into PHP.ini (PHP -v shows you all of this). For MySQL... You'd need to look at global setting which I'm forgetting at the moment.

Comment: The `date.timezone` setting in my "php.ini" file is set correctly.  Also, `system_time_zone` and `time_zone` variables in my MySQL server are set correctly.

Comment: What about Linux settings?

Comment: I'm running Windows.

Comment: No idea. I do not use Windows for production